# MBR/GPT confusion over dual booting Windows 10 Pro and Windows 10 Pro

Tags: boot, uefi, mbr, gpt, dualboot

I would like to install Windows 10 Pro twice on the same machine to have one partition for everyday use and the other for gaming (with the so-called bloatware).

According to the this link, I have to opt for MBR + Legacy BIOS:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dual-boot-windows-10-pro-with-windows-10-pro/4e9b990c-3ba2-49fe-b457-aaf07e139fd5

But if I understood correctly it means that Secure Boot cannot be enabled in BIOS, hence making my setup problematic if one day I decide to upgrade to Windows 11.

Is there no way I can use UEFI/GPT for what I'm after or I can simply opt for UEFI(CSM)/MBR hence being able to enable Secure Boot?

Comment: AFAIK GPT won't necessarily be a problem, but Secure Boot will, because it's designed to trace exactly one boot path.

Comment: That would be even worse ahead of Windows 11. Either way, Secure Boot will be disabled as I install both OSes, I will turn it back on after I'm ready. What I found so far in my research is to create an MBR USB Bootable Disk, enable UEFI CSM in the BIOS and install using MBR + UEFI CSM with Secure Boot disabled. When done, I will enable it.

Comment: You can't enable Secure Boot with CSM on because BIOS didn't support Secure Boot. It's a UEFI-only thing.

Comment: This page says otherwise: https://kb.stonegroup.co.uk/What-is-Secure-Boot-What-is-UEFI-Boot_212.html in the first Note box, hence my confusion.

Comment: @WPRookie82 - That page confirmed what we are saying.  If you enable CSM you cannot use Secure Boot

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean, but it's either incorrect or confusing. CSM is supposed to emulate BIOS and BIOS doesn't support Secure Boot. Maybe some implementations will still have Secure Boot support for UEFI boot targets while CSM is enabled. That's the only reasonable interpretation I can think of. I've never seen one though and it wouldn't make much sense anyway. The whole idea behind Secure Boot is to stop unauthorized bootloaders. The ability to bypass it with CSM would make it pointless.

Comment: @Ramhound - I was referring to the part, "In this mode, UEFI features are enabled, and things such as Secure Boot will still work." but it could be that I completely misunderstood the different options.

So the conclusion is that if I want to dual boot Windows 10 Pro and Windows 10 Pro I have to use MBR + Legacy with no Secure Boot and when it's time to upgrade to Windows 11 I would have to find a solution, correct?

Comment: Why don’t you just use UEFI without Secure Boot?

Comment: Because Windows 11 requires Secure Boot + TPM to be installed. I am aware of the registry hack but I doubt it will be active for a long period of time.

Comment: You haven't actually answered Ramhound's question. Why do you want to go with CSM for now rather than UEFI without Secure Boot?

Comment: I did, in my original post, the link to the Microsoft website where there is written that if Available CSM must be enabled. Also I was under the impression that MBR is not compatible with UEFI.

Comment: @WPRookie82 - If you have any desire to run Windows 11 when it's released, you will want to skip installing Windows 10 while in Legacy Mode, since Windows 11 only will support GPT (UEFI mode).  You can enable Secure Boot at any point provided you installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode.  If you install while in Legacy Mode, on a MBR partition, you will have to convert it later to GPT.  There are hundreds of questions on that process, MBR2GPT requires a specific setup, and based on what you want to accomplish your setup will be non-standard.  **You should use GPT today.**

Comment: @Ramhound I fully understand what you mean and I would be more than happy to go for GPT but that would prevent me from dual booting two Windows 10 Pros which is my ultimate goal, at least for now, until Windows 10 becomes obsolete in 2025.

Comment: "that would prevent me from dual booting two Windows 10 Pros" - No; It actually wouldn't prevent you from dual booting Windows 10.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, if I create a bootable USB with Rufus configured as GPT + UEFI and I configure my BIOS for UEFI without secure boot, I will not encounter the, "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of GPT Partition style." error during installation of the two Windows 10 Pro, correct?